# How do I stop Aurelia from throwing JS Errors, when clicking in page links (Fragment Identifiers) when it sees a # in the URL & attempts to reroute?

Tags: html, aurelia, router

With this simple anchor link & anchor target - originally defined by [Tim Berners-Lee](https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/) as a [HTML Fragment Identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-7.4) - is there a way to stop a false JavaScript error from appearing in [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/)?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#in-page-link">In Page Link</a>
...
<a name="in-page-link">The link scrolls/jumps here</a>
```

**JavaScript Router Error #1 (Not a real error):**

> Error: Route not found: /in-page-link

That's a false positive error. Of course it's not found! It's an in page link! It isn't a route! That JS "error" isn't a real error.

Is there a way to suppress that error, without having to over-engineer a JavaScript solution - to measure scroll heights & adjust the page offset - simply get around the flawed Node.js design paradigm, where routers *break* a basic [HTML feature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-7.4) to create regex paths AKA: routes? Why do I need to invent a JS fix for something a framework broke? If you break it, you fix it, right?

I've tried using Aurelia's [`router-ignore`](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/handling-links#skipping-click-hijacking) idea, but it doesn't work for links which start with hash tags. This similar SO answer doesn't work (& the 2nd line of the OP question was incorrect): [How do I keep on the same page by clicking on internal anchor links, using Aurelia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593660/how-do-i-keep-on-the-same-page-by-clicking-on-internal-anchor-links-using-aurel)

Is there a router configuration BYPASS feature, which won't try to re-route the URL to another location?
I've tried using `nav: false` in the router configuration, but it wants a `moduleId`. There *isn't* a `moduleId` for an in page link target.

With a basic router configuration [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) block like this...

```
{
   name: 'no_redirect',
   route: ['in-page-link'],
   nav: false
}
```

... how do I stop either the first JavaScript error (up above) or this additional JavaScript error from appearing, considering in page links won't have nor need to use these: `moduleId`, `redirect`, `navigation` nor `viewPort`? It's just an *in page* link.

**JavaScript Router Error #2:**

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid Route Config for "in-page-link": You must specify a "moduleId:", "redirect:", "navigationStrategy:", or "viewPorts:".

I'm trying to make this HTML link work, without having Aurelia throw false JavaScript errors into the console.log. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
<a href="#in-page-link">In Page Link</a>
...
<a name="in-page-link">The link scrolls/jumps here</a>
```

Comment: I think the router-ignore may do it: https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/handling-links#basic-concept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep on the same page by clicking on internal anchor links, using Aurelia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593660/how-do-i-keep-on-the-same-page-by-clicking-on-internal-anchor-links-using-aurel)

Comment: No. router-ignore doesn't work. I've already tried it.

Comment: No. That's the related link, which I mentioned doesn't have a working solution for in page anchor links AKA HTML Fragments. I had to comment on the OP's original code example, as their HTML code example was incorrect.

Comment: I just did a test on an aurelia project I have here and it worked fine using `router-ignore`, both using an `a` element with a `name` or any element with `id`, which is correct based on the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Oh that's interesting! I wasn't aware that the HTMl 4 spec added the ability to target the id instead of the name for in page anchor links. That's good to know! Thank you Leo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured out a solution for my problem!**

I tried getting it to work with anchor links & `router-ignore`, but neither of those worked out for the site that I'm building. Perhaps it's using an older version of Aurelia, which doesn't have that `router-ignore` feature yet? Maybe. I don't know. I didn't check.

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/527) for my 1st JavaScript error on GitHub. It also has an [interesting router configuration](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/527#issuecomment-349258603) in it, which would address my 2nd JavaScript error.

I've discovered a faster & simpler work-around, which other Aurelia developers might like!

I reached out to [Rob Eisenberg](https://twitter.com/EisenbergEffect), who was kind enough to point me to his [discord.aurelia.io](https://discourse.aurelia.io) site. While searching it, I found an [interesting work-around idea](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/normal-anchor-links-throwing-route-not-found-errors/1995)! After exploring it & [the related code examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsdiscourseaureliaiotnormal-anchor-links-throwing-route-not-found-errors1995-ve2kb), I was able to get the 1st false JavaScript error to disappear... *without having to over-engineer* any browser pixel measuring logic! I really didn't want to have to write any JS scrollbar math *again*, using `clientOffset` values. Here is [a good example of measuring the scrollbar height](https://tobbelindstrom.com/blog/measure-scrollbar-width-and-height/).

I have repeatedly written code like that in the past, but I wanted to avoid having to reinvent that wheel... yet again! I really wanted to figure out another way to fix this basic snag, without having to write any custom scrollbar math logic because it felt like I was writing too much code to fix a bug in the underlying framework. Other frameworks, besides Aurelia also suffer from hijacking the '#' in the URL to create routes. It appears to be a recurring issue in the Node.js community.

This **fast work-around** for Aurelia is super small, fast & easy to implement. Perhaps someone will enjoy this!

1. Change `<a href="#in-page-link">` to `<div class="link" click.trigger="jumpDown()">`.
2. Add a method into the behind-the-scenes matching JavaScript file, which sets a boolean:

```
jumpDown () {
   this.linkClicked = true;
}
```

3. Change `<a name="in-page-link">` to `<button class="btn" focus.bind="linkClicked">`.
4. Use CSS to style the link, plus add a `cursor: pointer;` property & hide any button styles, as desired.

So the final code would look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="link" click.trigger="jumpDown()">In Page Link</div>
...
<button class="btn" focus.bind="linkClicked">The link scrolls/jumps here</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jumpDown () {
   this.linkClicked = true;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn {
   /* Style as desired. */
}

.link { 
   color: #0000FF;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Then the original JavaScript error #1 vanishes! The link click still works! No additional router configuration is needed! Web developers look like web rockstars! The quality assurance team is happy! Problem solved!